# dgenpareto module in R jags

Tags: r, module, updates, jags, rjags

I have recently updated my R, Rstudio, and rjags packages. Below are the platform/versions I am running my R scripts on/with:

```
> version
_                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.0                              
year           2022                             
month          04                               
day            22                               
svn rev        82229                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
nickname       Vigorous Calisthenics            
> 


> library(runjags)
Warning message:
package ‘runjags’ was built under R version 4.2.1 

> library(rjags)
Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.3.1
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs
Warning message:
package ‘rjags’ was built under R version 4.2.1 

> library(R2jags)
Attaching package: ‘R2jags’
The following object is masked from ‘package:coda’:
    traceplot
Warning message:
package ‘R2jags’ was built under R version 4.2.1
```

I am running a jags model that contains the generalized Pareto distribution (GPD) as 'dgenpareto'. I use the following command lines to run my jags model:

```
> jags.parallel(model.file = bayes_gpd,data = jags.data,parameters.to.save = jags.params,
                                            inits = jags.inits,n.iter=50000,n.chains = 4,
                                            jags.module='runjags')
```

But I get the following Error message each time I try to evaluate my jags model:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
> 4 nodes produced errors; first error: File not found: C:\Program Files\JAGS\JAGS-4.3.1/x64/modules/runjags.dll

While I had no issue with running my jags model (the same code) before updating the R and jags packages. Could you please provide some hints on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was unable to resolve this issue as described above for a `rjags` model. However, I could convert my model code to a `runjags` model in which `degenpar` is already embedded. Here are the command lines to run the model in R in a parallel scheme:

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
> run.jags(model=bayes_gpd,
       data=jags.data,
       n.chains=4,
       burnin=4000,
       sample=n.iter,
       monitor=jags.params,
       method="rjparallel", cl=cl,
       modules="runjags")
```

Note that the following code syntax in `rjags`, as:

```
bayes_gpd <- function() {
YOUR MODEL/LINES
}
```

will be changed to a `runjags` model syntax as shown below:

```
bayes_gpd <- "model {
YOUR MODEL/LINES
}"
```